# Calculating a pooled odds ratio from an adjusted odds ratio?

Tags: stata, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I have individual adjusted odds ratios from different articles, and I want to combine them to calculate a pooled odds ratio, e.g., `aOR 2.13(1.43-3.18)` and `aOR 1.47(0.54-3.98)`.

So, is there any formula or guidance on how to combine them? The adjusted odds ratios are from articles, and I don't have the entire data set related to these two articles.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to give you a more complete answer right now, but you could start by taking a look at the documentation of the `metan` command.

Comment: Of possible interest: [Odds ratio and confidence interval in meta-analysis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26623/930).

Answer (score 4):

*Systematic Reviews in Health Care: Meta-analysis In Context* is an excellent resource if you're looking to do a meta-analysis (in healthcare or otherwise - if you're not in health, ignore their overt fondness for clinical trials).

They also include extensive documentation for conducting a meta-analysis in Stata beyond just a pooled estimate of effect. That is where I would head to first.